# изменить цвет другого Activity

Tags: android, textview

Eсть `Main_activity_1` и `Main_activity_2`, в `Main_activity_1` есть `but1` кнопка, хочу нажатием `but1` изменить background `TextView` (он находится в `Main_activity_2`):

Comment: Вы не можете напрямую манипулировать виджетами одной активити из другой, так как в один момент времени существует только одна активити.

Comment: Сохраняйте желаемые манипуляции в промежуточное хранилище, например Bundle (если вторая активии вызывается из первой) и передавайте его между активити через Intent. Одна пишет в него, другая получает и по полученным данным вносит у себя изменения. Если вторая активити вызывается не из первой или полученное состояние нужно сохранить для последующего использования, то пишите в постоянное хранилище, как SharedPreferences. Имена активити в Android принято писать без знака "_", в CamelCase стиле - MainActivity и давать им более осмысленные имена.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не могли бы вы дать пример в виде кода, или подскажите где я могу прочитать ? 
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Это невозможно. В один момент может работать только одна актвити. А раз других нет, то и манипулировать ими нельзя.

Вам надо так:

1. Сохранить куда-то что-то (цвет например, в виде строки)
2. Где-то как-то это что-то поменять (например, строку-цвет в `SharedPreferences`)
3. Где-то как-то это что-то достать и применить (например, строку-цвет из `SharedPreferences` применить к фону `TextView`)

Записываем цвет:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
pref.edit().putString("key", "#ff0000").apply();
```

Извлекаем:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String colorString = pref.getString("key", "#000000");
int color = Color.parseColor(colorString);
```

Применяем:

```
TextView textview = ...;
textview.setBacgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: Спасибо вы помогли, ваш ответ мне тоже был интересен, но у меня другая проблема, хочу в MainActivity_2 написать много кода и meнять visibility(пс. в MainActivity_2 все visibility="gone") когда я нажму but1 будет visible то что я захочу в MainActivity_2:
Есть ли способ такой монипуляции ?
Заранее спасибо:

Comment: @ArsenGhazaryan, вы меня запутали вам надо цвет менять? Если да, то получилось ли?

Comment: нажму but1(MainActivity_1) и TextView (MainActivity_2) вместо visibility="gone" станет visible:

Comment: @ArsenGhazaryan, зачем вы спрашивали про цвет если он вам не нужен?.. 0_о

Comment: Я приводил премер

Comment: @ArsenGhazaryan, ну, тогда и я пример, получается, приводил... Код из ответа можно для чего угодно применить. Просто сохраняйте/получайте не строку, но `boolean` значения